# Why is free radical chlorination exothermic whereas bromination is endothermic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, radicals, halogenation

In the energy profile diagrams below, it can be clearly seen that the free radical chlorination of an alkane

$$\ce{RH + Cl2 -> RCl + HCl}$$

is exothermic. However, the corresponding bromination

$$\ce{RH + Br2 -> RBr + HBr}$$

is endothermic. Why is there a difference?

[image]

Comment: That's because both reactions products, hydrohalogenide and halogenoalkane are more stable with chlorine. The orbital overlap is not as good in the case of the larger bromine.

Comment: [This](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66339/why-is-chlorine-and-not-fluorine-labelled-as-the-most-reactive-halogen-for-halog/66536#66536) earlier answer may be helpful.

Comment: It looks like your energy diagrams are for the first propagation steps not the full reaction [RH + X(dot) ---> R(dot) + HX]. You also need R(dot) + X2 ---> RX + X(dot) for the second step. Chlorination is more exothermic than bromination but both are exothermic.

Answer (score 1):

First off, we can see that both reactions are exothermic If we do the thermodynamic analysis.

Given that your starting materials have the same heat of formation:

$$\Delta H^\circ_f(Products) = \Delta H^\circ_f (\ce{R-H}) + 0, \quad{\Delta H^\circ_f(\ce{Cl}) = \Delta H^\circ_f(\ce{Br})= 0}$$

$$\ce{R = Et}\\ \Delta H^\circ_f (\ce{EtH}) = \pu{-84 kJ mol^{-1}}$$
$$ 
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\hline
\text{Product 1} & \Delta \text{H}^\circ_f [\pu{kJ mol^{-1}}] & \text{Product 2} & \Delta \text{H}^\circ_f [\pu{kJ mol^{-1}}] & \Sigma\ \Delta \text{H}^\circ_f\  [\pu{kj mol^{-1}}] &\text{Result}\\
\hline
\ce{HBr} & -\text{36.45} & \ce{Et-Br} & -\text{97.6} &-\text{134.05}<-\text{84} &\text{Exothermic} \\
\ce{HCl} & -\text{92.31} & \ce{Et-Cl} & -\text{137} & -\text{229.31}<-\text{84}  &\text{Exothermic}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

---

Back to your question:

> Why is there a difference?

The graphs you are looking at only consider the reaction:

$$\ce{R-H + X^. ->  R^. + HX}$$

For which we get:
$$ 
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\hline
\text{X}
& \Delta \text{H}^\circ_f(\ce{X^.})
& \Delta \text{H}^\circ_f(\ce{RH})
& \Delta \text{H}^\circ_f(\ce{R^.})
& \Delta \text{H}^\circ_f(\ce{HX})
& \Delta \text{H}^\circ_{rxn}
& \text{Result}\\
\hline
\ce{Br} & -\text{96.94}^{**} & -\text{84} & -\text{119}^\dagger &-\text{36.45} &\text{25.49}&\text{Endothermic} \\
\ce{Cl} & -\text{121.29}^{**} & -\text{84} & -\text{119}^\dagger & -\text{92.31} &-\text{6.02}&\text{Exothermic}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
*all units in $[\pu{kj mol^{-1}}]$ all values from Wikipedia unless otherwise stated 
** [Table of Bond Dissociation Energies](https://labs.chem.ucsb.edu/zakarian/armen/11---bonddissociationenergy.pdf)
$^\dagger$ Values from [NIST WebBook](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C2025561&Mask=1)

Here the enthalpy of radicalization of the alkane is different for chlorine or bromine, but the halogenation in total is exothermic